# mnesia:read return empty when use table fragmentation in mnesia , but have record

Tags: erlang, mnesia

`mnesia:read` returns an empty list when using table fragmentation in mnesia , but I do have a record:

My code is like this :

```
F = fun() ->
     mnesia:dirty_read({offline_msg, <<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11>>}) 
end.
Result = mnesia:activity(transaction, F, [],mnesia_frag).
Result is : 
[#offline_msg{userid = <<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11>>,timestamp =1547039796317984,from = 123}]
```

but

```
F = fun() -> 
    mnesia:read({offline_msg, <<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11>>}) 
end.
Result = mnesia:activity(transaction, F, [],mnesia_frag).

Result is  []
```

table info:

```
PrimProps = [{n_fragments, 64}, {n_disc_only_copies, 1}, {node_pool, [node()]}],
mnesia:create_table(offline_msg,
 [{disc_only_copies, [node()]},{type, bag},{attributes, record_info(fields, offline_msg)}, {frag_properties, PrimProps}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write the record to the table using `mnesia:dirty_write`?

The "dirty" functions (`dirty_read`, `dirty_write` etc) bypass Mnesia's table fragmentation, even if used inside `mnesia:activity` as in your first example: they always access the *first* fragment of the table.  So I suspect that what happened is this:

- the record was written to the *first* fragment using `mnesia:dirty_write`
- in your first example, `mnesia:dirty_read` looked for the record in the *first* fragment, and found it
- in your secord example, `mnesia:read` inside `mnesia:activity` used a hash of the record key to figure out which fragment the record *should* be in, and looked in that fragment - but the record is not present, since it was written to the wrong fragment.

---

If you want to use dirty operations with fragmented tables, call `mnesia:activity` with `sync_dirty` or `async_dirty`:

```
mnesia:activity(sync_dirty, F, [],mnesia_frag).
```

For example, to write the record to the table:

```
OfflineMsg = #offline_msg{...},
F = fun() -> mnesia:write(OfflineMsg) end,
mnesia:activity(sync_dirty, F, [],mnesia_frag).
```

This will let `mnesia_frag` ensure that the record gets written to the correct table fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How to wrote the record used a hash of the record key to fragment?

Comment: I added an example of that to the answer.